# Generically specifying a superclass in Swift

Tags: swift

It would be really nice (in writing tests for instance) to be able to write a piece of code that subclasses, say, any UIViewController. If I could make the name of the superclass a generic placeholder, I could write (total illegal pseudo-code!):

```swift
class MySubClass<TheSuperClassType: UIViewController>: TheSuperClassType {
    override viewDidLoad() {
        // my stuff goes here
    }
}
```

That way I could uniformly subclass any UIViewController with exactly *one and the same* piece of code, rather than having to repeat myself, subclassing *each* UIViewController *separately*. Is there any way to express the superclass "dynamically" like that? I don't believe Swift permits it, but maybe there's some trick that I'm not coming up with.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-there-possible-to-support-inheriting-from-a-generic-type-class-classa-t-classb-t/21541